# BAT failed copy command - continue after &&?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, copy

So I have tried to search for solutions online, but could not find any.
Basically, I have a command like this:

```
for /D %%X in (s*) do copy f1.txt %%X\f1.txt && copy f2.txt %%X\f2.txt
```

However, if f1.txt does not exist, I get a `The system cannot find the file specified` and f2.txt is NOT copied for the given directory.

How can I get around this to have f2.txt copied even if f1.txt does not exist?
Note, I can't simply split into two different lines because I have these copy statements in a huge `for` loop with many commands.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your response JMC. It led me to find this [web page](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true).

There, I found that I should change the && to an & actually:

> command1 & command2: Use to separate multiple commands on one command line. Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then the second command.

So it should be:

```
for /D %%X in (s*) do copy f1.txt %%X\f1.txt & copy f2.txt %%X\f2.txt
```

Comment: Correct. The command that follows `&&` executes only if the previous one didn't fail. And with `||`, by the way, it's just the other way: the next command is invoked only of the previous command did fail. You need `&` if you want both to run independently of each other's result.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `&&` to the `||`